# If else condition to create a new column

Tags: python, pandas, string, if-statement

I am trying to create a new column "name_correct" that removes special characters in the name column in the df below. Additionally, I also want to create a flag column that populates to 1 if a correction was made. In the code below, name_correct is created as expected but the binary flag is 1 for all when it should be 1 for row 1 and 0 for the rest. Can someone help me in correcting this? Thanks!

```
d= {'name': ["AÃÑA", "23234", "BJORK", "3","JANEDOE123"]}

df=pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=[0, 1, 2, 3,4])

df

# remove special characters if there are any & correct_flag=1 if correction was made
if df['name'].str.contains('|Ã|Ñ').any():

    df['name_correct'] = df['name'].str.translate(str.maketrans('ÃÑ','AN'))

    df['correct_flag'] = 1

else:
#if no correction is made, name_correct = name and correct flag=0.
    df['name_correct'] = df['name']

    df['correct_flag'] = 0

print(df)
```

Comment: You're setting `correct_flag` in all rows, not just the rows that meet a condition.

Comment: The condition is being applied to the entire df -- if there are any names containing those characters, you set `correct_flag = 1` in all rows.

Comment: Why do you have an if-else in the first place? It looks like you meant to write a loop but then put in a vectorized Pandas operation instead. You can just do the `translate` and don't bother checking.

Comment: I think you want to use `np.where()`, it allows you to assign different things to rows whether that row matches a condition.

Comment: I think you want `df['correct_flag'] = df['name_correct'].eq(df['name'])`. Add `.astype('int')` if necessary.

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't have `|` at the beginning of the regexp. That will match an empty string, and everything contains that.

Comment: @wjandrea
I think you meant **ne**  so as to get the OP flag correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not your question, but a faster solution and more bulletproof solution is to replace accent letters in python, you can use [unicodedata.normalize](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize)

```
df['name_correct'] = df['name'].str.normalize('NFKD')\
             .str.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')\
             .str.decode('utf-8')
df['correct_flag'] = df['name'] != df['name_correct']
```

output :

```
         name name_correct  correct_flag
0        AÃÑA         AANA          True
1       23234        23234         False
2       BJORK        BJORK         False
3           3            3         False
4  JANEDOE123   JANEDOE123         False
```